"cannot find name Chart" when trying to use chart.js
I have a really annoying problem with chart js which I am stuck for some days now, I've tried literally everything but couldn't figure out yet.
The problem is, I'm using a simple TypeScript environment with ES modules in it, I tried importing Chart but with no luck, it gave me the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
I searched over internet and found there isn't a practical solution for it, and I should resort to another method and so I did, which is using global UMD link and so I did import the script to my html:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.1/chart.umd.js"></script>

but there is another problem now: this is the error that is give this error when I try to use new Chart saying that chart can't be found: Cannot find name 'Chart'.ts(2304)
I am really out of options here, I hope someone can help me in this.
this is my package.json:
{
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tsc-watch": "^6.2.0"
  }
}

and this is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ES2022",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDirs": ["**/*", "src"],
    
  },
  "include": ["src/"]
}

and this is the file where is causing error on new Chart, remembering, I've already tried importing with no luck, it gives an error on the browser:
import { diagnosisHistoryProps } from './patientsData.js';

function chartData(diagnosis_history: diagnosisHistoryProps) {
  const bloodPressureHTML = <HTMLCanvasElement>(
    document.getElementById('blood-pressure')
  );

  if (bloodPressureHTML) {
    new Chart(bloodPressureHTML, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: diagnosis_history.map((row) => row.year),
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Blood Pressure',
            data: diagnosis_history.map(
              (row) => row.blood_pressure.diastolic.value
            ),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
}

export default chartData;

I've tried everything, and searched everywhere but unfortunately with no luck yet.

You can just ignore the line where you run new Chart(). You could add a typescript ignore:
  if (bloodPressureHTML) {
    //@ts-ignore
    new Chart(bloodPressureHTML, {
      type: 'line',

This will prevent typescript from parsing types for that line. You will not get proper type annotation for this as new Chart() as will be assumed to return any type. You will need to cast it yourself or save it to a variable with a defined type already. However, this will allow for your code to compile. Afterwards as long as you have the script tag in your <head> to load the library then it should work just fine in the browser.
The issue comes if you need the type annotation. You will need to either get the library to work or import just the type definitions which usually are @types/[packageName], but these usually require the library itself as well I believe.

Well, I will try this but I don't know if it will work or if even the new Chart itself is working since I tried importing it inside of a .js file already and it passed me the same error only without with this red line under new Chart that typescript makes more clear, the thing is, even the chart itself isn't appearing for me in the client.

After adding the script tag to your raw html head and making typescript ignore the line, what is the error you are getting?

Oh I didn't get any error, only it wasn't showing on screen but it was my own fault. I forgot putting a canvas tag and it wasn't recognizing chart but fixed now, and your answer fixed the linting error, thank you.
